# How to Write In Clause with EF FromSql?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.1

I have an unknown amount of parameters for my inclause. How can I write it so it works with EF Core?

```
  var formattedValues = String.Join(",", values.Select(s => "'" + s + "'"));
            var identifierParam = new SqlParameter("jsonColumn", $"$.{identifierKey}");
            var filterValueParam = new SqlParameter("value", $"%{formattedValues}%");

            var items = dbContext.Items.FromSql("select * FROM Items WHERE  AND JSON_VALUE(Attributes, @jsonColumn) in (@value)", filterValueParam, identifierParam).ToList();
```

I think it is because each value in the in clause needs it's own Parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using SQL Server, you can pass the list of values as JSON.  EG

```
  var jsonValues = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values.ToList());
  var filterValueParam = new SqlParameter("@values", jsonValues );
  var identifierParam = new SqlParameter("@jsonColumn", $"$.{identifierKey}");

  var sql = "select * FROM Items WHERE  AND JSON_VALUE(Attributes, @jsonColumn) in (select value from openjson(@values))";

  var items = dbContext.Items.FromSql(sql, filterValueParam, identifierParam).ToList();
```

Comment: Cool, is the select part being done in memory or at the db side? I am just wondering if there will be a performance hit.

Comment: The client sends a JSON string (nvarchar(max)) to SQL Server.  SQL Server parses the string as a table and runs the query.

Comment: This was brilliant, thank you! Using EF Core and Azure SQL Server, it sped up a 50,000 record query that was previously using batching from ~15 seconds to 3 seconds, and was much cleaner to boot (was able to condense it down to a one-line statement). This needs to be publicized more, it took a lot of searching to find this solution to the traditional large IN clause query problem.