# EF Core: Create a SQL user-defined type from a C# class

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In my SQL database I have stored procedures and functions that take table valued parameters. I can create the table valued parameter and populate it from any List of entities of type T with pure C# like this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
var columns = props.Select(p => new DataColumn(p.Name, p.PropertyType));
table.Columns.AddRange(columns.ToArray());

List<T> entities = GetEntities();
foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(entity);
    }

    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

var tvp = new SqlParameter("@Entities", table) { TypeName = "dbo.T", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured };
```

But in order to pass the above TVP to the stored procedure one must create a corresponding user-defined type T in sql server first. So far I am unable to find a way to do this without using raw SQL. Like this:

```
-- I want to avoid this
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[T] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
)
```

Is there a way to define the SQL user-defined list from the C# type T without having to write SQL? Somewhere there are already libraries that map C# to SQL types, I don't want to reinvent the wheel and write SQL code that is difficult to maintain and can easily get out of sync with the C# class.

Answer (score 8):

After hours of research I reached the same conclusion suggested by David Browne, it can't be done natively.
However not all is lost, I managed to extend the default EF Core SQl Generator to allow me to manually create and drop user defined table types in migrations using the same pure C# syntax for creating and dropping tables, without mentioning SQL datatypes (e.g nvarchar). For example in a migration file:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateUserDefinedTableType(
    name: "T",
    schema: "dto",
    columns: udt => new
    {
        // Example columns
        Id = udt.Column<int>(nullable: false),
        Date = udt.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
        Memo = udt.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true)
    }
);
```

I am sharing the code below:

```
/// <summary>
/// A <see cref="MigrationOperation"/> for creating a new user-defined table type
/// </summary>
public class CreateUserDefinedTableTypeOperation : MigrationOperation
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     The name of the user defined table type.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The schema that contains the user defined table type, or <c>null</c> if the default schema should be used.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Schema { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     An ordered list of <see cref="AddColumnOperation" /> for adding columns to the user defined list.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual List<AddColumnOperation> Columns { get; } = new List<AddColumnOperation>();
}



/// <summary>
/// A <see cref="MigrationOperation"/> for dropping an existing user-defined table type
/// </summary>
public class DropUserDefinedTableTypeOperation : MigrationOperation
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     The name of the user defined table type.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The schema that contains the user defined table type, or <c>null</c> if the default schema should be used.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Schema { get; set; }
}



/// <summary>
///     A builder for <see cref="CreateUserDefinedTableTypeOperation" /> operations.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TColumns"> Type of a typically anonymous type for building columns. </typeparam>
public class UserDefinedTableTypeColumnsBuilder
{
    private readonly CreateUserDefinedTableTypeOperation _createTableOperation;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Constructs a builder for the given <see cref="CreateUserDefinedTableTypeOperation" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="createUserDefinedTableTypeOperation"> The operation. </param>
    public UserDefinedTableTypeColumnsBuilder(CreateUserDefinedTableTypeOperation createUserDefinedTableTypeOperation)
    {
        _createTableOperation = createUserDefinedTableTypeOperation ??
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(createUserDefinedTableTypeOperation));
    }

    public virtual OperationBuilder<AddColumnOperation> Column<T>(
        string type = null,
        bool? unicode = null,
        int? maxLength = null,
        bool rowVersion = false,
        string name = null,
        bool nullable = false,
        object defaultValue = null,
        string defaultValueSql = null,
        string computedColumnSql = null,
        bool? fixedLength = null)
    {
        var operation = new AddColumnOperation
        {
            Schema = _createTableOperation.Schema,
            Table = _createTableOperation.Name,
            Name = name,
            ClrType = typeof(T),
            ColumnType = type,
            IsUnicode = unicode,
            MaxLength = maxLength,
            IsRowVersion = rowVersion,
            IsNullable = nullable,
            DefaultValue = defaultValue,
            DefaultValueSql = defaultValueSql,
            ComputedColumnSql = computedColumnSql,
            IsFixedLength = fixedLength
        };
        _createTableOperation.Columns.Add(operation);

        return new OperationBuilder<AddColumnOperation>(operation);
    }
}



/// <summary>
/// An extended version of the default <see cref="SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator"/> 
/// which adds functionality for creating and dropping User-Defined Table Types of SQL 
/// server inside migration files using the same syntax as creating and dropping tables, 
/// to use this generator, register it using <see cref="DbContextOptionsBuilder.ReplaceService{ISqlMigr, TImplementation}"/>
/// in order to replace the default implementation of <see cref="IMigrationsSqlGenerator"/>
/// </summary>
public class CustomSqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator
{
    public CustomSqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator(
        MigrationsSqlGeneratorDependencies dependencies,
        IMigrationsAnnotationProvider migrationsAnnotations) : base(dependencies, migrationsAnnotations)
    {
    }

    protected override void Generate(
        MigrationOperation operation,
        IModel model,
        MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
    {
        if (operation is CreateUserDefinedTableTypeOperation createUdtOperation)
        {
            GenerateCreateUdt(createUdtOperation, model, builder);
        }
        else if(operation is DropUserDefinedTableTypeOperation dropUdtOperation)
        {
            GenerateDropUdt(dropUdtOperation, builder);
        }
        else
        {
            base.Generate(operation, model, builder);
        }
    }

    private void GenerateCreateUdt(
        CreateUserDefinedTableTypeOperation operation,
        IModel model,
        MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            .Append("CREATE TYPE ")
            .Append(Dependencies.SqlGenerationHelper.DelimitIdentifier(operation.Name, operation.Schema))
            .AppendLine(" AS TABLE (");

        using (builder.Indent())
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < operation.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                var column = operation.Columns[i];
                ColumnDefinition(column, model, builder);

                if (i != operation.Columns.Count - 1)
                {
                    builder.AppendLine(",");
                }
            }

            builder.AppendLine();
        }

        builder.Append(")");
        builder.AppendLine(Dependencies.SqlGenerationHelper.StatementTerminator).EndCommand();
    }

    private void GenerateDropUdt(
        DropUserDefinedTableTypeOperation operation,
        MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            .Append("DROP TYPE ")
            .Append(Dependencies.SqlGenerationHelper.DelimitIdentifier(operation.Name, operation.Schema))
            .AppendLine(Dependencies.SqlGenerationHelper.StatementTerminator)
            .EndCommand();
    }
}




public static class MigrationBuilderExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Builds an <see cref="CreateUserDefinedTableTypeOperation" /> to create a new user-defined table type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TColumns"> Type of a typically anonymous type for building columns. </typeparam>
    /// <param name="name"> The name of the user-defined table type. </param>
    /// <param name="columns">
    ///     A delegate using a <see cref="ColumnsBuilder" /> to create an anonymous type configuring the columns of the user-defined table type.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="schema"> The schema that contains the user-defined table type, or <c>null</c> to use the default schema. </param>
    /// <returns> A builder to allow annotations to be added to the operation. </returns>
    public static MigrationBuilder CreateUserDefinedTableType<TColumns>(
        this MigrationBuilder builder,
        string name,
        Func<UserDefinedTableTypeColumnsBuilder, TColumns> columns,
        string schema = null)
    {
        var createUdtOperation = new CreateUserDefinedTableTypeOperation
        {
            Name = name,
            Schema = schema
        };

        var columnBuilder = new UserDefinedTableTypeColumnsBuilder(createUdtOperation);
        var columnsObject = columns(columnBuilder);
        var columnMap = new Dictionary<PropertyInfo, AddColumnOperation>();

        foreach (var property in typeof(TColumns).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties)
        {
            var addColumnOperation = ((IInfrastructure<AddColumnOperation>)property.GetMethod.Invoke(columnsObject, null)).Instance;
            if (addColumnOperation.Name == null)
            {
                addColumnOperation.Name = property.Name;
            }

            columnMap.Add(property, addColumnOperation);
        }

        builder.Operations.Add(createUdtOperation);

        return builder;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Builds an <see cref="DropUserDefinedTableTypeOperation" /> to drop an existing user-defined table type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"> The name of the user-defined table type to drop. </param>
    /// <param name="schema"> The schema that contains the user-defined table type, or <c>null</c> to use the default schema. </param>
    /// <returns> A builder to allow annotations to be added to the operation. </returns>
    public static MigrationBuilder DropUserDefinedTableType(
        this MigrationBuilder builder,
        string name,
        string schema = null)
    {
        builder.Operations.Add(new DropUserDefinedTableTypeOperation
        {
            Name = name,
            Schema = schema
        });

        return builder;
    }
}
```

Before migrations can work with the above code, you need to replace the service in the DbContextOptions, in your Startup's Configure services (with ASP.NET Core) like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(opt =>
    opt.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("MyContextConnection"))
    .ReplaceService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator, CustomSqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator>());
```

Relevant links:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations
2. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.1/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Migrations/SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.cs

Comment: Before anyone judges this to be an overkill, consider that we heavily rely on user defined table types to perform bulk operations on the database as this is a common use case in our software. We have a user defined table type for almost every table.

Comment: This is such a good response. It delivers exactly what is needed, has full code I could literally drop in to my project, anticipated a likely issue (adding the custom sql generator) and has references.

One of the best answers I've seen on SO recently. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of anything that generates the User Defined Table Types for an Entity.  You already have to keep your C# classes in sync with the database tables, so you would tack the Table Type generation process onto that.

An alternative is to pass the data to SQL Server using JSON instead of a TVP.  EG: [How to Write In Clause with EF FromSql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016130/how-to-write-in-clause-with-ef-fromsql/53024174#53024174)