# Too long expression using Predicate Builder

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Am using PredicateBuilder to dynamically build expression in Entity Framework.

For example:

```
var expression = PredicateBuilder.New<Person>();

foreach(var person in People)
{
   expression = expression.Or(p => p.Name == person.Name && p => p.Surname == person.Surname && p => p.Address == person.Address)
}
```

It working fine, but when I have a lot of data, it is not possible to build such a long expression. I mean, when I get for example 1000 people, i am getting exception, that expression could be so long.

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: If you want to build a query that compares a thousand values on three different fields, you have a different problem. Even if your expression would compile, you're going to bring your database down on its knees. Why do you want this? Why haven't you looked into an alternative?

Comment: This three fields in only an example.
I need to have expression with multiple OR statemets and I could not find any other alternative to do it.

Comment: Like joining a temp table?

Comment: You could also look into [Table-Valued Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) but you can't use it with an predicate builder or Lamda/Linq syntax (AFAIK).

Comment: If this is SQL Server, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016130/how-to-write-in-clause-with-ef-fromsql

Comment: for each would go over each record. did you try .Where(expression) ? 
check what SQL query it creates...