# EF Core error "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Transfers with unique index" when trying to update a row

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to update ([MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state#entity-states-and-savechanges)) multiple rows without knowing the primary key and without fetching each row first as I might have hundreds or thousands of rows to update.

**Scenario** - I have a webhook that's coming into my controller and it provides me with a list if Stripe transfer ids (ex. "12345", "67890", "111111"). I have a table called Transfer that has this column 'StripeTransferId' but it's not the primary key for the table.

**Problem** - I need to loop through each entry from the webhook and update each entity in my DB without knowing the primary key and without fetching each row before hand, as there might be thousands of rows to update.

Here is an example of what I need to do

```
[HttpPost("stripe")]
public async Task<IActionResult> StripeWebhook()
{
     // parse and read data from webhook
     // get a list of stripeTransferIds from the webhook data
     // loop through each id and update corresponding row in db
     foreach(string stripeTransferId in stripeTransferIds) {
         // change the status of the transfer in the DB to complete and update
         var existingTransfer = new Core.Entities.Transfer { TransferStatus = TransferStatus.Complete, StripeTransferId = transferId };
         _context.Attach(existingTransfer);
         _context.Entry(existingTransfer).State = EntityState.Modified;
     }
     
     _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     
}
```

Doing this I get an error below saying it's trying to insert and not update the row

> Message [string]:"Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Transfers' with unique index 'IX_Transfers_StripeTransferId'. The duplicate key value is (tr_1KNMXEH6wPz6LzpKxzl1Q39h).\nThe statement has been terminated."

FYI - If I comment out the line that attaches the entity I get an error saying 0 rows were affected.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a table called Transfer that has this column 'StripeTransferId' but it's not the primary key for the table. . . . I need to loop through each entry from the webhook and update each entity in my DB without knowing the primary key and without fetching each row

If StripeTransferId has a unique index then you can treat it as the key.  Just configure the entity with that as the Key, and your update using a stub entity will work.  EF doesn't care which unique index, unique constraint, or Primary Key constraint you use for the entity key.

Or use a [Raw SQL Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) to perform the update, which is probably your best bet. Especially since you might be able to send all the (StripeTransferId, State) pairs to the database in one call using a [Table-Valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15), [JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016130/how-to-write-in-clause-with-ef-fromsql/53024174#53024174), XML, or a comma-delimited string (depending on your RDBMS).

Comment: Hi David. I'm a little hesitant to change the primary key to this other property(column). I don't believe I have any other queries on "Transfer" that search by the primary key (ID). But I know I have FK to other tables. Question - Can I create a composite key w/ the primary key (ID) if one of the two properties can be null, or do they both have to be non null. And would I then be able to update on just that one key in the composite? Also what about alternate keys https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=fluent-api#alternate-keys

Comment: A composite key won't work.  You'd need both values to perform an update.  You can also introduce a special DbContext subtype with the alternate key mapping if you want.  But really a Raw SQL Query is probably your best bet.  Especially since you might be able to send all the (StripeTransferId, State) pairs to the database in one call using a Table-Valued parameter, JSON, XML, or a comma-delimited string (depending on  your RDBMS).

Comment: Hi David. I'm using SqlServer in Azure. Question - If I do a Raw SQL Query, wouldn't I have to write the SQL into a string type and then have EF read it, or can it be done strictly with EF and Linq? Also I'm not that experienced on the backend, what do you mean by "send all the pairs to the database in one call using a Table-Valued parameter"? Do you have any examples you can provide me?

Comment: Hi David. Another issue is that I can't make the column StripeTransferId a primary key because it is nullable.

Comment: Again, you're not making it a Primary Key, that's an RDBMS concept.  You're making it the Entity Key.  EF doesn't care whether it's the _real_ primary key.

Comment: How do you make something a Entity Key without making it a primary key? I'm looking here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations. Either way my column value is nullable, so I don't know if it's possible?

Comment: I've added links for TVF and JSON.  Those will definitely be much faster than sending single-row update statements.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you use await in your original code.  Since attaching is not working I would try this

```
var existingTransfers = await _context.Set<Transfer>().Where(t=> 
 stripeTransferIds.Contains (t.StripeTransferId ).ToListAsync(); 

foreach(var item in existingTransfers)
item.TransferStatus = TransferStatus.Paid;

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

this way you can put everything in one transaction. If you have a very large quantiy of Ids maybe it makes a sense to user raw sql string or even a stored procedure to increase performance

Comment: I can't fetch the row before I update it. I actually have the updating code in for loop that updates hundreds and possibly thousands of rows, so I can't fetch each one to update it.

Comment: @user1186050 You have to post all classes with the real code are you using and explain what is the real problem not that you posted already. Maybe we can offer another way, but I am not sure.

Comment: Ok let me post more code with more explanation.

Comment: Hi Serge. Doesn't this fetch all the entities before I update them? Also doesn't .ToList also fetch all data? Isn't this really inefficient?

Comment: @user1186050 Yes, you are right, it will fetch all records according to your Ids list. But since it  is only one  trip to db and a very simple select without joins I don't see that it will affect performance very much. The most time takes a connection and security verification but you will do it only once.  But It can help EF to generate more efficient t-sql script so It seems to me that the more eficient will be only the sending raw sql  script to db servert. You can generate this script using list of Ids the way you like it.

Comment: Hi Serge. I'm concerned that if I fetch all the rows first like your example, I will also fetch all the data, resulting in a massive hit to my DB and CPU. Do you know if your solution using .ToListAsync() will fetch all the row data?

Comment: @user1186050 Not all data, only according your Ids list. How many items it can contain? Do you know how to use debugger? you can always check how many records it is - existingTransfers.Count

Comment: What do you mean "not all data", will it fetch some data, which data? Will it only fetch the StripeTransferId property? The list could contain a few hundred to 1-2 thousand rows at most. Most of the time it will contain <100 rows but could contain <1000

Comment: @user1186050 I mean not all rows in the db, only rows with selected Id. I thought you have only one property except Id. In this case the way are you trying is wrong, if you want to update the record you will have to create and attach the whole object, not just 2 properties and I don;t  know how you can do it without fetch the whole row. If you don't like it  then the only way is to generate your own sql script.

Comment: Hi Serge. Here's the the thing, the row has lots of data in it with lots of columns. I don't want to fetch all that data if I only need to update 1 column.

Comment: @user1186050 If you create and empty object with 2 properties assigned, all another properties will became empty during update. It  is  your problem that you create a giant table. Move status to a separate table with 2 columns only.